# How can I import functions from an other javascript file?

Tags: javascript, import, module, export

I'm pretty new in JS, and I have some trouble with importing.

I'm doing a Star Wars planet list application, where I'd like to import functions from an other JS file like this:

--- dataManager.js ---

```
export function getAllPlanetDataFromAPI() {

    let allPlanetsInfo = new XMLHttpRequest();
    allPlanetsInfo.open('GET', 'https://swapi.co/api/planets');
    allPlanetsInfo.onload = function () {
        console.log(allPlanetsInfo.responseText)
    };
    allPlanetsInfo.send();

}
```

--- main.js ---

```
import { getAllPlanetDataFromAPI } from './dataManager';

getAllPlanetDataFromAPI();
```

The error message I get is: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"

Seems like the syntax is incorrect, but I have already checked all of the "import" articles on the web, and couldn't find what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you use webpack or rollup for instance to convert your ES code in standards Javascript?

Comment: Are you using html file to load these scripts or any framework like react?

Comment: Have you tried with removing curly brackets `{` on import?

Comment: I did not use webpack or rollup.

@yaswanth I'm loading these files in my index.html, like this:

<script src="../static/js/main.js" defer></script>
<script src="../static/js/dataManager.js" type="module"></script>

Comment: @niccord I have tried it aswell, then the error is: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

I've also tried to import everything from the file with "*", then the error was: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *"

Comment: for the main.js file also you can specify type="module". But you wil be facing CORS issue here. You can server these files using any server to resolve CORS issue.

Comment: @yaswanth In addition, I use Flask to run my app. I don't know if it has anything to do with my problem by the way

Comment: Try this one `export const getAllPlanetDataFromAPI = () => {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out!

The main problem was that I haven't added the "type="module"" attribute to my main.js file in my HTML. After that I got an other error: "404- Not Found", and I could fix it by adding ".js" after my import. So the perfectly working code is:

--- index.html ---

```
<script src="../static/js/main.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="../static/js/dataManager.js" type="module"></script>
```

--- dataManager.js ---

```
export function getAllPlanetDataFromAPI() {

    let allPlanetsInfo = new XMLHttpRequest();
    allPlanetsInfo.open('GET', 'https://swapi.co/api/planets');
    allPlanetsInfo.onload = function () {
        console.log(allPlanetsInfo.responseText);
    };
    allPlanetsInfo.send();

}
```

--- main.js ---

```
import { getAllPlanetDataFromAPI } from './dataManager.js';

getAllPlanetDataFromAPI();
```

Thanks for all of the answers and comments, especially @yaswanth who moved me in the direction of the solution!

Comment: In addition I dont even need the this line in my html:

<script src="../static/js/dataManager.js" type="module"></script>

Answer (score 0):

in es6 you can use import { getAllPlanetDataFromAPI } from './dataManager' otherwise you should import ./dataManage

Comment: The first version is in the question, that does not work.

The secon one gives me an error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string" :(

Answer (score -2):

You should change your file extensions to **.mjs** 
then run your code with these command:

node --experimental-modules main.mjs

please feel free to ask me in comments.

Comment: has nothing to do with nodejs whatsoever.